# How long will take to run future method?

Tags: future

How long will future method take to run in a class. I'm executing a class which consist one future method. The class is executing is fine but i'm waiting for future method result since long time ago. will it update immediately or  will take time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out Setup > Monitoring > Apex Jobs. They will appear here with a status.